# how can i import routes from another module to my app.py and make them work?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, web, routes

Tried to import routes from another module and the page always shows 404 and the route is not there, even though i imported them and a message appear like " "routes"(this is my module name) is not accessedPylance ".

[These are the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9bTo.png)

## **app.py :**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, redirect
from functools import wraps
import pymongo


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key 

# Database
client = pymongo.MongoClient
db = client.movie_project

# Decorators
def login_required(f):
  @wraps(f)
  def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
    if 'logged_in' in session:
      return f(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
      return redirect('/')
  
  return wrap

# Routes

from user import routes

@app.route('/')
def home():
  return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/dashboard/')
@login_required
def dashboard():
  return render_template('dashboard.html')

app.run(debug=True)
```

## user/routes.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from app import app
from user.models import User

@app.route('/user/signup', methods=['POST'])
def signup():
  return User().signup()

@app.route('/user/signout')
def signout():
  return User().signout()

@app.route('/user/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
  return User().login()
```

the route import doesn't work, if anyone has an idea please tell me i'm stuck !!!!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The routes you defined in `user/routes.py` have to be attached to the current instance `app` of your Flask server which is initialized in `app.py`.

One solution should be to encapsulate your routes in a function and pass the `app` instance as an argument:

- `user/routes.py`

```py
from user.models import User

def routes(app):
  @app.route('/user/signup', methods=['POST'])
  def signup():
    return User().signup()

  @app.route('/user/signout')
  def signout():
    return User().signout()

  @app.route('/user/login', methods=['POST'])
  def login():
    return User().login()
```

- `app.py`

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key 

# Database
client = pymongo.MongoClient
db = client.movie_project

# Decorators
def login_required(f):
  @wraps(f)
  def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
    if 'logged_in' in session:
      return f(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
      return redirect('/')
  
  return wrap

# Routes

from user.routes import routes
routes(app)

@app.route('/')
def home():
  return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/dashboard/')
@login_required
def dashboard():
  return render_template('dashboard.html')

app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: hey thank u for ur answer but now it appears there's another problem and it's : "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" , this appeared after I tried ur solution.

Comment: Yes I edited my answer, the import statement should be `from user.routes import routes` rather than `from user import routes`